# What percentage of android users allows the google play app to use the "location" permission?

Tags: android, google-play

I know that all users of old android versions have the "location" permission granted for the "google play" app (in fact, they can't turn it off). But for an informal sample in the office, it seems that users of newer android phones all have the permission off.

Is it off by default? Does it ask for permission to use location on first launch?

Does anyone know statistics as to how many users allow the "google play" app to use the "location" permission?

Comment: Do you mean how many people leave location services turned off on their device?  I doubt there are any hard numbers, but my guess is "a lot".  This was especially true in the older days when battery life was precious and seemingly every app needed to know exactly what street corner you were on at all times thus constantly pinging the GPS.

Comment: No, I am asking about app permissions (an app has a list of permissions that, on modern android phones, can be granted or not by the user, like "location", "camera", "contacts", "storage" ...)